# Bind the value of an input component to a list item by index

Tags: jsf

here is an example :

```
 <h:outputLabel for="category1" value="Cateogry"/>
 <h:selectOneMenu id ="category1" value="#{articleManageBean.categoryId1}" 
   converter="categoryConverter">

     <f:selectItems value="#{articleManageBean.categories}" var="category"
         itemValue="#{category.id}" itemLabel="#{category.name}" />

 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

and here is the managed bean that I have

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ArticleManageBean {

   private Long categoryId1;
   private List<Category> categories;

   //...
}
```

The categories list gets populated from db, and selectOneMenu gets populated with this list using a converter.

My First question: 
If I want to create another selectOneMenu in my jsf page I would have to copy paste the entire thing and just change the value of selectOneMenu to say categoryId2 thus putting another attribute to managed bean called categoryId2. That is not practical. I want to map these values of selectMenu to list items, for instance to an  attribute

```
 List<Long> categoryIds;
```

if I use

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id ="category1" value="#{articleManageBean.categoryIds.[0]}"  >
```

I get an error

```
 javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /createArticle.xhtml @47,68 value="#{articleManageBean.categoriesId[0]}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

If I nitialize the Araylist then I get this exception

```
 javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /createArticle.xhtml @47,68 value="#{articleManageBean.categoriesId[0]}": null
```

My second question:
Is there a way to dinamicly write selectOneMenu tags, by that I mean not to copy paste the entire tag, just somehow create a function that take the categoryId parameter and writes automaticaly the tag (somekind of custom tag maybe ?)

Hope you understood my questions

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the brace notation instead to specify the index.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="category1" value="#{articleManageBean.categoryIds[0]}">
```

You only need to make sure that you have already prepared the values behind `#{articleManageBean.categoryIds}`. JSF won't do that for you. E.g.

```
private List<Long> categoryIds = new ArrayList<Long>();

public ArticleManageBean() {
    categoryIds.add(null);
    categoryIds.add(null);
    categoryIds.add(null);
    // So, now there are 3 items preserved.
}
```

an alternative is to use `Long[]` instead, this doesn't need to be prefilled.

```
private Long[] categoryIds = new Long[3]; // So, now there are 3 items preserved.
```

Comment: If Use that I get an exception
 javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /createArticle.xhtml @47,68 value="#{articleManageBean.categoriesId[0]}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null

Comment: You of course need to make sure that the `categoryIds` is not `null`. Assign a `new ArrayList<Long>` on initialization or bean's construction.

Comment: After I did that now I get exception for items of araylist javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /createArticle.xhtml @47,68 value="#{articleManageBean.categoriesId[0]}": null

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I got confused with difference in behaviour when using `List` or `Object[]`. I have improved the answer.

Comment: yes thanks Ive used something like that and it worked. Any idea about my second qestion?

Comment: Just use `ui:repeat` or `c:forEach`.